# TypeError on react navigation 5 drawer,tab,stack and auth all in one

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make an app that has drawer, tab and stack navigators but I can't make it work.

[Code here](https://codeshare.io/5wBXY9)

[image: Error here]

Comment: Are `react-navigation/native` and `react-navigation/stack` up to date? See [this issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8175)

Comment: Yes, all up to date